# How do you make a filter for images that have tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I have products in a grid using the code below. I wonder how to make a filter so that when the user clicks a box that says for example "green", the site only shows the images that have a green tag.

How do you make such a filter and how to do apply tags?

ps. I dont mean `<div>` kind of tags, i mean "Oh that jersey is a: "Hoodie" "Green" "Zipper", ect. Just thought i'd clarify that."

thanks in advance :)

HTML:

```
<div id="Backgrounds">                                
                            <img id="Hajar" src="Backgrunder/Hajar.jpg">
                            <img id="Labyrint" src="Backgrunder/Labyrint.jpg">
                            <img id="Martini" src="Backgrunder/Martini.jpg">                              
                            <img id="FärgadePapper" src="Backgrunder/FärgadePapper.jpg">
                            <img id="Hajar" src="Backgrunder/Hajar.jpg">
                            <img id="Labyrint" src="Backgrunder/Labyrint.jpg">
                            <img id="Martini" src="Backgrunder/Martini.jpg">                               
                            <img id="FärgadePapper" src="Backgrunder/FärgadePapper.jpg">
                            <img id="Hajar" src="Backgrunder/Hajar.jpg">
                            <img id="Labyrint" src="Backgrunder/Labyrint.jpg">
                            <img id="Martini" src="Backgrunder/Martini.jpg">                                
                            <img id="FärgadePapper" src="Backgrunder/FärgadePapper.jpg">
                            <img id="Hajar" src="Backgrunder/Hajar.jpg">
                            <img id="Labyrint" src="Backgrunder/Labyrint.jpg">
                            <img id="Martini" src="Backgrunder/Martini.jpg">                               
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#Backgrounds img{
    width: 97px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Where are those tags, how are they defined?

Comment: also - some of the image ids are repeated. this is wrong.

Comment: Just using the same images for now since im lazy :P about the tags, that was my question, how sould i add these tags and how can i use them to filter through the images?

Comment: so you are too lazy to write a proper question but expect people to write an answer for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest storing a comma delimited list of strings in a **[data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)**, then iterating through the images and filtering that way. For example:

***HTML***

```
<div id="backgrounds">
    <img id="Hajar" data-tags="hoodie,zipper,green" src="Backgrunder/Hajar.jpg">
    <img id="Labyrint" data-tags="these,are,tags" src="Backgrunder/Labyrint.jpg">
</div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
function filterImages(tag) {
    // select all the images
    var query = document.querySelectorAll('#Backgrounds img');

    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
        var image = query[i];

        // hide the image if it doesn't contain the tag we're looking for
        if (image.getAttribute('data-tags').split(',').indexOf(tag) === -1)
            hideImage(image);
    }
}

function hideImage(image) {
    // do whatever you need to "filter" out the image
    image.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Sry im not that experienced, in which variable do i send the tags that the user has chosen? and how?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to do this. You just have to find a way that's right for you.

I'm not sure on all of your requirements but [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) has [filtering](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html) that is pretty easy to use. Here's a [demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html).

If you need a little more control you can look into [TaffyDB](http://www.taffydb.com/) and generated the HTML based on the results of a query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i'll go with Isotope, looks perfect for what i need!